# Get delta in Deltasnapshot in Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, database-trigger

I am using an onUpdate trigger in firebase cloud functions.

```
exports.addInvitation = functions.database.ref(`eventList/{pushId}/invitations`).onUpdate(event => {
console.log(event.data.val())
console.log(event.data.delta())
})
```

with `event.data.val` I have access to the value after the change. With `event.data.previous` I can access the value before the update. But is there anyway I can only get the change. Logging the `event.data.delta` in firebase I see: 
[image: firebase log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you meant to say "With `event.data.previous` I can access the value **before** the update".

The delta property you're seeing in the dump is not part of the public API for [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot).  So I don't recommend reaching into it, since it could change without notice.

To find out if some data changed in a DeltaSnapshot, you're supposed to use the [changed()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#changed) method.  Or, you can compare the `event.data.val()` and `event.data.previous.val()` yourself.